# Bootstrap Glyphicons don't show in IE10 or FF

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons

I'm having trouble getting the bootstrap glyphicons to show in IE10 or FF. I'm using the latest bootstrap 3 code and am including the glyphicons the standard way:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
```

They work fine in Chrome, however in IE10 they aren't visible and generate errors in console:

```
CSS3111: @font-face encountered unknown error. 
glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
CSS3111: @font-face encountered unknown error. 
glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
CSS3111: @font-face encountered unknown error. 
glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
```

Interestingly, they work locally in IE10, but not remotely.

In FF they show the "E034" icon, which I assume means image not found?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]It works for ME in IE10. Do you have below files in your fonts directory

```
glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg
glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
```

I Used to display time icon beside my article.

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
```

Comment: Yes I have all of those. Again, it works locally, just not remotely in IE, so I don't think it's a file path issue.

Comment: This ended up being my own stupidity, I had included the font files but hadn't set their type as Content in my ASP.NET MVC project so they weren't copied over on publish.

Comment: @Justin, the font files are marked as of type 'Content' by default. Glad this worked for you anyway...

Answer (score 0):

It's worth noting that bootstrap 3 icons as well as other styling failing to appear properly with ie10 can sometimes be fixed by adding  to force the latest IE version.

Further, everything may appear fine locally; but you may need the meta tag from the server.