# Bootstrap 3.3 Internet Explorer 10 Glyphicons Not Showing

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer

Glyphicons are not being rendered on Internet Explorer 10. They are correctly rendered on both Chrome and Firefox, as well as Internet Explorer 11.

The icons do render when served locally, but not when on a remote server (I'm not sure if that fact that it is served through HTTPS makes a difference).

Based on other related questions, this is what I have tried and does not work:

1) The console shows no errors indicating there's been an issue.

2) There are no 404s when downloading the fonts.

3) The headers and mimetypes are correctly being set in the response.

4) I have tried replacing the fonts with a fresh download of bootstrap's fonts.

5) Internet Explorer 10 security policy set to allow for downloads of web fonts.

It seems like there is no problem whatsoever, but nothing is rendered for the font.

Comment: I would investigate the urls properly (since it works locally and not remotely, which usually exposes some only urls/paths problems, relatives vs absolutes, maybe some missing dots here and there). Maybe you dont see 404s, but they are not loaded anyway. Prepare an fiddle with the problem and im pretty sure you will fix it doing the fiddle ;-)

Comment: @Pavelloz the path of the font being downloaded does exist and I can manually go to it. It also works correctly on other browsers.

Comment: Have you tried fiddling with order of the font-face declarations? Meaning: removing all but one-by-one to cross out that IE10 needs a fallback that it didnt receive?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I'm thinking it's https as my local and staging site don't show any font-face over https

Comment: If I remember correctly, I had explicitly set the font family for all elements within my custom CSS which would then override the bootstrap icons as it was loaded afterwards. I excluded all elements with the class of glyphicon from my custom font. Basically it was trying to load glyphicons with Helvetica.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap Glyphicons don't show in IE10 or FF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19200433/bootstrap-glyphicons-dont-show-in-ie10-or-ff)

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete or comment out font-face property in your css file that overrides bootstrap.css, it causes the problem with displaying glyph icons (e.g. on safari).

Answer (score 0):

If font downloads are disabled in your Internet Explorer security settings the Bootstrap icons will never render. Just tested this out for a similar problem I faced on IE installations that had a high security policy set by a system admin.